# Print node URL in a custom block template

Tags: theming, 8, uri, navigation

I have a custom block that loads multiple nodes from the database and passes it to the twig template.
Inside the template I loop the list printing some node details, but I need to create a link on the node title, possibly its clean (alias) URL. The problem is that with node.url I get a security error:

> Twig_Sandbox_SecurityError: "Calling "url" method on a "Drupal\node\Entity\Node" object is not allowed

I tried with `{{ link(item.label, item.url.value) }}` but I get the same error.

What is the correct way to create a link in twig using the node URL?

Comment: Use the preprocess function to pass the node URL to the template. Anyway, you don't say how you pass nodes to the template. Also, since the question seem about code, the question would be much more helpful to future users if it shows the code too.

Comment: You should use preprocessor as mentioned above. Also, I haven tried, but see if maybe {{ attribute(node, 'toUrl') }} works.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it seems I have solved the problem using twig/drupal path() function, building the linked title in this way:

```
<a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': item.id}) }}">{{ item.label }}</a>
```

where "item" is the node object inside the list loop.